# Detect view visibility in hidden fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, visibility

Is there any way to detect if a view changes visibility when the fragment it belongs to is shown/hidden?

The fragment has a method `onHiddenChanged()` to notify about changes in visibility.

A view however only has callbacks to notify when its attached or detached from the window. Is there any way of detecting the visibility change **inside the view** (not by calling a public view method via the fragment)?

Those are the methods I've tested:

- `onAttachedToWindow()`: not called on fragment `show()` / `hide()`
- `onDetachedFromWindow()`: not called on fragment `show()` / `hide()`
- `getGlobalVisibilityRect()`: returns true (visible) regardless if the fragment is shown/hidden

**Important**: The view is stand alone. It must not have a reference to the fragment and vice versa, the fragment must not call any method on the view.

Alternatively, is there any method to detach the fragment's view hierarchy from the window without destroying its views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @bigO is working very well, however there is a much simpler solution:

```
@Override
protected void onVisibilityChanged(@NonNull View changedView, int visibility) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
    Log.d(TAG, visibility == View.VISIBLE ? "visible" : "invisible");
}
```

This view method is called each time the fragment is shown/hidden with the respective values of `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE`

Answer (score 3):

About the first question, `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` may work.

```
yourView.setTag(yourView.getVisibility());  //set this somewhere in your code, maybe after you create the view

yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int newVisibility = yourView.getVisibility();
        if((int)yourView.getTag() != newVisibility)
        {
            Log.d("VISIBILITY_CHANGE", "Visibility Changed");
        }
    }
});
```

About your second question, yes there is a method to detach the fragment's view hierarchy from the window without destroying the fragment. You can use FragmentTransaction class's `detach()` method.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commit();
```

> Detach the given fragment from the UI.  This is the same state as when it is put on the back stack: the fragment is removed from the UI, however its state is still being actively managed by the fragment manager.  When going into this state its view hierarchy is destroyed.

Comment: 1.: I'll expand my question to clarify the fragment / view issue
2.: detach() does not work because as I stated the view hierarchy must not be destroyed.

Comment: @McFarlane I thought you said you do not want the fragment to be destroyed.

Comment: You are right, the question could be interpreted differently. I've updated it for clarification.

Comment: Thanks that shoved me in the right direction. The only change that was required was to use isShown() instead of getVisibility() because the latter only returns the visibility of the view itself. I've made an edit to your answer, pending review.

Comment: Turns out that there is a specific view method for the exact problem I'm having which I've completely overlooked... More coffee it is, then.